# Unable to zoom in and zoom out of chart in altair - python

Tags: python, altair

I am unable to make the chart interactive using altair python.

I have pasted the code below,

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame([
    {"task": "A", "start": '2021-12-03 11:00:00', "end": '2021-12-03 12:00:00'},
    {"task": "B", "start": '2021-12-03 13:45:00', "end": '2021-12-03 15:30:00'},
    {"task": "C", "start": '2021-12-03 19:20:00', "end": '2021-12-03 20:45:00'}
])

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='start:N',
    x2='end:N',
    y='task'
).interactive()
```

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Nominal axes cannot have scale-bound selections (i.e. cannot be "zoomed"). Try using a temporal encoding instead:

```python
alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='start:T',
    x2='end:T',
    y='task'
).interactive()
```

If you want the y axis to be interactive, this is more difficult because Vega-Lite does not support panning and zooming of nominal axes, and nominal is the only appropriate encoding for string categories.

But you can get around this with the pretty terrible hack of mapping your data to numbers, then using a quantitative bin transform and re-mapping the numbers back to axis labels. For example:

```python
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

source = pd.DataFrame([
    {"task": "A", "start": '2021-12-03 11:00:00', "end": '2021-12-03 12:00:00'},
    {"task": "B", "start": '2021-12-03 13:45:00', "end": '2021-12-03 15:30:00'},
    {"task": "C", "start": '2021-12-03 19:20:00', "end": '2021-12-03 20:45:00'}
])

source['tasknum'] = [0, 1, 2]

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='start:T',
    x2='end:T',
    y=alt.Y('tasknum:Q',
        bin=alt.Bin(extent=[-0.5, 2.5], step=1.0, nice=False),
        axis=alt.Axis(values=[0, 1, 2],
                      labelExpr="{0:'A', 1:'B', 2:'C'}[datum.value]"))
).properties(
    height=150
).interactive()
```

To be quite honest, though, I wouldn't actually do this, and instead I'd just live with the limitation that nominal axes cannot be zoomed or panned, or (if this is not sufficient) find another plotting package that does what you want.

Comment: If I use temporal encoding, I am able to zoom along x-axis and not y-axis. I want zoom functionality to work for both x and y axis

Comment: OK, see my edited answer.

Comment: This is not working. The values in dataframe keeps changing. So how to dynamically do that

Comment: You could probably dynamically map inputs to unique indices and generate the appropriate vega expression to remap them, but it would be messy. Like I said, the fundamental issue is that **this is not supported by Vega-Lite**. If the hack I included above doesn't work for you, you should either learn to live with this limitation or find a new plotting package that can do what you want.