# How to make bar chart interactive on both x and y axis using altair

Tags: python, altair

How to make bar chart interactive. I mean I want to scroll both x-axis and y-axis.

I have pasted code below,

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('graph.csv')
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(orient='vertical').encode(
x = alt.X('SWIPE_START_DATETIME'),
x2 = alt.X2('SWIPE_END_DATETIME'),
y='NO_OF_HOURS',
tooltip=['SWIPE_START_DATETIME','SWIPE_END_DATETIME','NO_OF_HOURS']
).interactive()
```

I am able to scroll along one axis using above code.

Can someone help me modify the code

Comment: According to this https://altair-viz.github.io/altair-tutorial/notebooks/06-Selections.html. Just adding `.interactive()` allows you to drag and scroll to pan and zoom on the plot on both x and y axis. So, it's weird that you couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is the same as the answer to the [question you posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70234890/unable-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-of-chart-in-altair-python).

Vega-Lite, the renderer used by Altair, does not support panning/zooming on nominal or ordinal axes. If adding `.interactive()` doesn't work, it indicates that your data is nominal or ordinal.

If your columns contain strings representing temporal data, you can use `:T` in the encoding to ensure that it's treated as a time rather than as a string category.

Otherwise, there are hacky workarounds you can do (as in my answer to the linked question), but fundamentally the issue is Vega-Lite does not support panning/zooming of nominal or ordinal axes.